# SAS list and store all tables name under specify library to a table

Tags: sas

Under library "testing", i have 5 datasets. How can i list all tables names?

```
proc datasets lib = work; quit; run;
```

While i would like to have further usage of the information. like the tables name.

Thanks

Comment: Please research before posting on SO.  The answer to this can be found by googling anything with the words "sas list datasets", "sas list tables", etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the SQL `dictionary.tables` view...

```
proc sql ;
  create table mytables as
  select *
  from dictionary.tables
  where libname = 'WORK'
  order by memname ;
quit ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Proc sql;
     select *
     from sashelp.vmember
     where libname = "TESTING" 
  ;
quit;
```

Make sure to put the library name in upper case.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are correct but it can often take a long time to build the `sashelp.vmember` or `dictionary.tables files`.
This will have better performance especially on the first run.

```
proc contents data=testing._all_;
  ods select members;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

More likely the user wants this solution which is quick and creates the table:

```
proc contents data=testing._ALL_;
ods output members=work.temp;
run;
```