# Proc Sort Multiple datasets

Tags: sas

I am trying to proc sort and then merge more than 30 datasets. 
I am thinking of using the following macro to do the proc sort, but I wonder if I can do use some sort of do loop to achieve this more efficiently.

```
 %macro sort (data= )
    proc sort data = &data;
    by state;
 run; 
%mend sort;

%sort (data=Ads_nodup_20050414_20050513);
%sort (data=Ads_nodup_20050514_20050613);
.
.
.%sort (data=ADS_nodup_20150514_20150613);
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140551/looping-through-arguments-in-a-macros-in-sas/31140971#31140971) is probably applicable.

Comment: Also, consider a SQL join which doesn't require a pre-sort.

Comment: Don't I still have to name each different dataset individually even if I use SQL join?

Comment: A %DO loop may be possible if there is a pattern in the name of your datasets?  The first two names you listed are the same, so I can't tell if there is a pattern.  Can you edit your question to show the first 5 dataset names, and the last name?  If it's just some sort of date suffix should be doable.   I suppose other option would be to build a list of the dataset names from dictionary.tables.

Comment: I agree that linked duplicate is sufficiently similar to this.  Not a fan of the only-one-solution there as there are lots of other ways to do it; that might be good to use as a canonical question though and include some other answers there.

Comment: I edited the question: Sorry. but there is a pattern the dataset is divided by year and mid monthly. So the first dataset is for the month of mid april to mid may 20050414_20050513 and second one is from 20050514_20050613 (mid may to mid june). Therefore I thought it may be possible to do a do loop of sort

Comment: @Joe I see this as a question about how to generate a list of dataset names (and then loop over them), which is different than the linked question where it is not possible to generate the names.  I think the linked question may work as canonical question for "how to call a macro iteratively, passing arguments from a list" or some such.  List generation is a separate issue, IMHO.

Comment: @Quentin If there were more information in the question, perhaps.  The OP doesn't include that in the question - so as it stands it's completely duplicated by the duplicate, IMO; the duplicate explains how to execute a macro multiple times.  Given the lack of information of how to create the parameters for the dataset, that part isn't answerable or relevant (and, frankly, shouldn't be difficult to figure out).

Comment: @user2916331 Assuming you can create a dataset that has (as one variable per row, one row per macro call) that name, the duplicate should answer your question as to how to call the macro that many times (it's not a "do loop" but it's close).  You can certainly create a dataset with relative ease for a pattern like yours; it's also possible you could use a dictionary.tables lookup to construct that dataset, but you don't give enough information about what your initial environment is here (is this "merge all of the datasets with this prefix and some date after it"?)

Comment: @user2916331 Here is what I was thinking of as a iterative %do loop approach, using %intnx to make the date part of each name.   %macro sort (startdate=,nmonth=3) ;
  %local i date1 date2 ;
  %do i=0 %to %eval(&nmonth-1) ;
    %let date1=%sysfunc(intnx(month,&startdate,&i,S),yymmddn8) ;
    %let date2=%sysfunc(putn(%sysfunc(intnx(month,&startdate,&i+1,S),8.)-1,yymmddn8)) ;
    proc sort data = Ads_nodup_&date1._&date2 ;
      by state;
    run; 
  %end;
%mend sort;

Comment: See [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012681/sas-list-and-store-all-tables-name-under-specify-library-to-a-table/27013251#27013251) for an example for how to build a table having the names of all tables in it.  Add additional WHERE conditions to subset to tables looking like your name (`where libname='WORK' and substr(memname,1,10)='ADS_NODUP_'` perhaps).